# R: Matching and repeating occurence

Tags: r, dataframe, matching

(sample code below) I have two data sets. One is a library of products, the other is customer id, date and viewed product and another detail.I want to get a  merge where I see per each id AND date all the library of products as well as where the match was. I have tried using full_join and merge and right and left joins, but they do not repeat the rows. below is the sample of what i am trying to achieve.

```
id=c(1,1,1,1,2,2)
 date=c(1,1,2,2,1,3)
 offer=c('a','x','y','x','y','a')
 section=c('general','kitchen','general','general','general','kitchen')
 t=data.frame(id,date,offer,section)

offer=c('a','x','y','z')
 library=data.frame(offer)
######
t table
  id date offer section
1  1    1     a general
2  1    1     x kitchen
3  1    2     y general
4  1    2     x general
5  2    1     y general
6  2    3     a kitchen

library table
  offer
1     a
2     x
3     y
4     z
```

and i want to get this:

```
  id date offer section
1  1    1     a general
2  1    1     x kitchen
3  1    1     y  NA
4  1    1     z general
...
```

(there would have to be 6*4 observations)
I realize because I match by offer it is not going to repeat the values like so, but what is another option to do that? Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `complete` to get all combinations of `library$offer` for each `id` and `date`.

```
tidyr::complete(t, id, date, offer = library$offer)

# A tibble: 24 x 4
#      id  date offer section
#   <dbl> <dbl> <chr> <chr>  
# 1     1     1 a     general
# 2     1     1 x     kitchen
# 3     1     1 y     NA     
# 4     1     1 z     NA     
# 5     1     2 a     NA     
# 6     1     2 x     general
# 7     1     2 y     general
# 8     1     2 z     NA     
# 9     1     3 a     NA     
#10     1     3 x     NA     
# … with 14 more rows
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `tidyr` and `dplyr` to get the data. The `crossing()` function will create all combinations of the variables you pass in

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
t %>% 
  select(id, date) %>% 
  {crossing(id=.$id, date=.$date, library)} %>% 
  left_join(t)
```